# Why does this C++ thread example not work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I am trying to compile the following example and I am getting an error. Below is the code :

```
class A {
    private:
     //variables

    public:
      A(int a,int b){
        //assign variables
      }
      void C(){
         // do something
      }
       int D(){
       // do something
       }
       void E(){
       }
  }; 
 int main(){
    A* temp = new A(a,b);
    temp->C;
    std::thread t;
    t(&A::D,A);
    t.join();
    temp->E;
    return 0;
 }
```

I get the following error when I compile the above code with `pthread` and `std=c++11` flags. The following is the error message :

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 t(&A::D,A);
```

Comment: There is no`#include` list. In `main()`, there is no `a`. There is no`b`. `temp->C;` make no sense. likewise for `temp->E;` `t` is not "callable", and even if it were, `A` is a type and thus makes no sense as a parameter. Crawl, walk, *then* run. None of those errors have anything to do with threading.

Comment: An object of type `std::thread` doesn't have an `operator()` so the expression `t(...)` is invalid. Try `std::thread t(A::d, a);`?

Comment: I have abstracted all those details inorder to simplify the question

Comment: @Charlie Works great. Do you know how I can have an array of threads ? I tried using `std::thread my_threads[i](....)` but it says `Bad Array initializer` ? Please add your answer so that I accept it

Comment: @rajkiran added as an answer with additional comments for your follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some things here as an answer.

The first part of the question was an answer to the original comment. The constructor for `std::thread` takes the function to run. There's no additional `operator()` within the thread class, so to run `A::d`, you need to do:

```
std::thread t(A::d, a);
```

That will start the thread running that function.

The follow on question of how to do an array of threads... Since this is c++, consider a vector instead. If you have a vector of `A`, or `A*` you could do something like.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::vector<A> as;
... initialize as, for instance as.push_back(A(...)); ...
for (auto&& a : as) { threads.emplace_back(A::d, &a); }
for (auto&& t : threads) { t.join(); }
```

Note: when using emplace_back, the arguments are the constructor arguments for the type in the vector, not objects of that type. You could also use emplace for setting up the `vector<A>`. If you want a `vector<A*>`, then you don't need to do `&a` on the thread construction.